# How can Java versions older than 8 not support Closures?

Tags: java, java-8, closures

I read that `Java 8` supports `Closures`, but I just wanted to know that as any `function` inside a `class` can access a global variable, so how can Java previously didn't support `Closures` ?? See below example.

```
public class HelloWorld{
  int number = 5;
  public void fun() {
    System.out.println("number: " + number); // Here fun() can access number.
  }
  public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World");

    new HelloWorld().fun();
  }
}
```

I think there is something about `Closures` which I didn't get ??

Comment: I think you're confusing scope with closure, closures in java were done by using inner classes which is pretty awful and verbose.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that could be thought of as a closure prior to JDK-8 is *inner classes*.

So what is a closure?

A closure is pretty much like a lambda, except they reference variables outside the scope of the function. in other words, a closure is some type of behaviour which you can pass around and it references variables outside of its scope.

What Java-8 has done is provide closures with a more attractive syntax than inner classes.